# Getting values using same variables in different functions in a class

Tags: php, class, function

I have an issue with getting values using same variables in different functions in a class.

```
class base_functions{
    var $id;

    function get_user_details($user_id){
         $this->id = "1";           
    }

    function set_user_details($user_id){
         $this->id = "2";           
    }

}

   $obj_base_functions=new base_functions();
```

Now I need to get values from both functions set_user_details() and get_user_details(), is it possible,if there is any solution for this please let me know, thanks in advance fellas.

Comment: Please try to explain in greater detail what kind of values are you trying to get here.

Comment: I'll get values from database, I have different kinds of users. i need to get their details in a same page. so i created and  object in the page :

$oBaseFunctions=new base_functions();/* Object created for the base class in class-functions.php*/
    /* function is in class-functions.php */
  $oBaseFunctions->get_user_details();
  $oBaseFunctions->set_user_details();

 echo $oBaseFunctions->id;// using this i get only one value from this function $oBaseFunctions->set_user_details(); but i want to get both values.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if this is what you are looking for, but based on your code get & set methods are setting variable, and returning nothing. If you want to get those 2 different values all the time, use different variables, if not, this should work:

```
$obj_base_functions=new base_functions();
$obj_base_functions->get_user_details('');
print $obj_base_functions->id; // will print 1;
$obj_base_functions->set_user_details('');
print $obj_base_functions->id; // will print 2;
```